# How to deploy .NET [framework] web app to docker

Tags: .net, docker, rest

I want to build my .NET wep (api) application so I can have a docker image to distribute. So far, everything I have seen, talks about .NET core but since I'm using WCF, I'm using .net framework. I saw that it's possible to add support for docker on the project I created on Visual Studio which I did. However, I don't know how to actually build the api to get the image. I'm new to Docker so any help is very appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If it is not self hosted you have to get a docker image with a Webserver installed. You should dig through the docker documentation and search for an preinstalled docker image for WCF services. It's not easy explained in a forum post :)

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. It is possible to run that on a linux server? The problem is that I want to run a .net framework web api on a linux server using docker. Is such thing possible? From what I have seen, WCF is not supported by .net core so I cannot change the type of project. I use WCF as a client (to consume a service)

Comment: https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet-framework-wcf/ This is the image you need. It's windows. You cannot run framework 4.x on linux. The docker image itself can run on Linux.